# How to deal with In-App Purchase correctly?

Tags: objective-c, in-app-purchase

I'm new in In-App Purchase, and i've got problem with it.

Now buying process looks like:

1. Click YES and prepare to purchase with `UIAlertViewDelegate` method.
2. `paymentQueue:updatedTransaction` is Called with case: `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing`.
3. Next is called the same method with case `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased`. My feature is unlocked in this state (this state should be on end of purchase process)
4. Key about purchasing is stored to the keychain.
5. Again is called step 2.
6. Here is the question about buy feature (generated by StoreKit). Feature was unlocked before buying - user can cancel purchase now.
7. On end i've got above method with case `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` because item was buought in step 3.

Where is problem? How can i fix it?

This is my code:

```
#pragma mark - UIAlertViewDelegate Methods
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

if (alertView == askToPurchase) {

    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
    //prepare to purchase            
        SKProductsRequest *request =[[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:
                                     [NSSet setWithObject:completeIdentifier]];
        request.delegate = self;
        [request start];
    }
    else {
    //...
    }
}
}

#pragma mark - SKProductsRequestDelegate Methods
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
int count = [response.products count];

if (count > 0) {

    validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];

    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:completeIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}
else {
// item not available.
}
}


#pragma mark - SKPaymentTransactionObserver Methods
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {

for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {

    switch (transaction.transactionState) {

        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
        {
           //processing...            
            break;
        }

        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
        {
    //purchased.

            NSError *error = nil;
            [STKeychain storeUsername:identifier andPassword:@"Purchased" forServiceName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier] updateExisting:YES error:&error];

            if (error) {

                // Error with store key in keychain.
            }

            [self.delegate TSIAPHelperResponse:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                               identifier, @"identifier",
                                               [NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE], @"success",
                                               nil]];
            break;
        }

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
        {
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
    // restored.            
            break;
        }

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
        {
            if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
        //failure..                   
            }

            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
    //cancelled.            
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }
}
}

- (void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request {

}

- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
// failed to connect
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this tutorial is the best one to describe the **in app purchases** purchase process correctly

[in app purchases](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial)

Comment: Thank you but i saw the problem is with my delegate method. When i commented it that purchasing process is ok, but feature isn't unlock. I think how correctly call this delegate method after purchasing process.

Comment: Thank you! i forgot about `finishTransaction`.